# Jhipster translate on Input placeholder

Tags: jhipster

I m still new to Jhipster, I m using the latest version.

I want to know if there is any way to use the `jhiTranslate` on an `input` placeholder

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this snippet

```
<input placeholder="{{'register.messages.firstname' | translate}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can find all language translation properties in the src/main/webapp/app/shared/language folder

for more detail you can check the jhipster documentation it is very easy and useful 
https://www.jhipster.tech/installing-new-languages/

Comment: I have read all the documentation on jhipster translation before comming here, thanx

but the question is how to translate an input placeholder.